# How the home page UI of this website is build?

Tags: user-interface, web

How they managed to ensure that it looks like image behind an image while scrolling?

https://www.freecharge.in/#

Answer (score 1):

The effect you're looking for is called parallax. [This article](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/) has a fairly good explanation. A relevant plugin for the effect [can be found here](https://github.com/IanLunn/jQuery-Parallax).